# What gives the actual group count on tokenize in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I am using split().tokenize( with groupcount. I need to know the count in the last group because that coule be less that configured count.

how to find this number ?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation of the Splitter in the section *Exchange properties* http://camel.apache.org/splitter where you can see a table of the values stored on the Exchange with details of the split size and others.